# Where can I find DirectShow plugin that VLC needs?

Tags: windows, windows-10, vlc-media-player, directshow

On my previous attempt to record both video and audio 'from the desktop' only the sound portion was recorded. I suspect that the problem lies here, in the absence of a DirectShow plugin. (I couldn't find mention of one amongst the plugs in the VLC folder.)

Full text of the message that appears when you hover over 'Default' is 'Name of the video device that will be used by the DirectShow plugin. If you don't specify anything then the default device will be used.'

Assuming that I've correctly diagnosed my problem, where would I find one?

Thanks for your assistance!

[image: item indicated]

Comment: Are you trying to capture the Desktop or from a DirectShow capture device.  If the desktop, the "Capture Mode" dropdown should have a "Desktop"option.

Comment: The plugin exists there by default.  DirectShow was part of DirectX, but later simply made a feature of the Windows SDK.  So any program that implements, when it was installed, placed everything it needs on your system.

Comment: @heavyd: Thanks for responding. When I'm playing a video in Chrome, say, I would like to capture the video with its audio simultaneously with vlc. Somewhere in my tortuous journey on the 'net I've read that it's best to select DirectShow. But I could be persuaded to select something else. ;)

Comment: So, DirectShow is typically used to capture from capture devices like a webcam.  I would say that capturing your desktop is probably not a common use of DirectShow, however I also don't think the VLC built in desktop capture will capture at an acceptable framerate to capture video playback.

Comment: @heavyd: Don't ask me why but I somehow suspected that. Very good to have confirmation.